# Listen for push notification on url - Odoo

Tags: python, post, odoo

Is there any way of listening for a POST on a certain url within a custom module in Odoo?

Or would this have to be done with nginx redirecting the request to another python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can

```
from openerp import http

@http.route('/home', auth="public", website=True)
    def cart(self, **kwargs):
        return 'This is the index page'
```

it's pretty straight forward, we define a url route that points to `/home` and then a python method that returns a string to the user.
install your module and visit `localhost:8069/home` and you should see `'This is the index page'` returned back to you

for more information you get read the [docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/website.html)